# ETA for Australia after got denied evisitor visa

Tags: visas, australia, eta

I was denied an eVisitor visa for Australia because I had already spent two years in Australia and thought I would get another eVistor visa for a reason other than holiday.

I really for holidays before undertake my working holiday visa in NZ.

So after I was denied I applied for an ETA "visa" and was approved.

- Am I allowed in Australia or not?
- Am I going to have problems at the airport?
- In case they don't let me in can I go straight to NZ as I have a visa for NZ?

---

Clarification:

I'm Italian. I came back from Australia in December, after 2 year of WHV. Last week I applied for Evisitor (so after about one month I was home), because I have a WHV for NZ and I thought to pass from Australia first to visit places that I didn't see while I was there. 
My reason to go to Australia is purely tourism.

When I apply online I got email from immigration officer that I have to send them more information.
I answered them with my holiday plan in Australia attached with accommodations from first few dys, my visa for NZ, my ticket out from Australia to NZ, my bank account with sufficient funds...  They still refuse my visa because for them I don't have genuine intentions in Australia.

They said, I already spend 697 day in Australia under WHV and the main purpose of WHV is holidays, not working. But I didn't work more then 6 months for the same employer and I didn't abuse WHV at all, I stayed under all the condition about this visa and I also travelled a lots while a was there. But we all know how big is Australia. 
There are places I didn't see, that is why before go to NZ (now that I have money from Christmas and some savings) I wanted to go first for holiday to Australia before undertake my WHV in NZ.

This is not fair because now I have a denied visa in my passport for reason that they can't even prove (that means every time I apply for visas for other country I have to declare I got a denied visa in Australia), and I have flight booked to Brisbane that I can't change as it was under a saver fare.

So after I got denied for evisitor I wanted a transit visa, so I could get my flight to Brisbane and then take the flight to NZ, and I found  this ETA visa, I apply online throught a travel agent and I got approved after 5 minutes.

How does this work? Why did I get denied from evisitor and approved for ETA, when the purpose is the same?

Am I going to have problems at the airport? 
Will it appear on them computer when I pass the immigration counter that I have been denied from evisitor? Can I apply again for evisitor?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  I am not quite sure I understand what your question is?  Did you receive a visa or not?  And what does: *I really for holidays before undertake my WHV in NZ* mean?

Comment: @Karlson - WHV = Working Holiday Visa. I think she wants to vacation in Australia on the way to taking the job in New Zealand. ETA = Electronic Travel Authority. Valid for trips of up to three months, an ETA is automatically linked to your passport once approved.

Comment: One more question.  Based on your question I understood it that you were able to stay in Australia for 2 years on an eVisitor visa.  How did you manage this without violating the conditions of the eVisitor visa?

Comment: @wbogacz I think it's a she.  And I understood the WHV and NZ and ETA.  I'd like to know what the sentence means together.

Comment: Apparently SHE seems to have been denied a visa for Australia, then the ETA website gave her one, and SHE wants to go to NZ, after an Australia vacation. Will SHE have troubles? Denied/Not Denied - which prevails? I think SHE's OK.

Comment: @wbogacz She was denied Subclass 651 visa and granted Subclass 601 visa this is not a question and she has WHV visa for NZ.  I'd like the OP to clarify the meaning of the sentence I quoted.

Comment: I _suspect_ "I really for holidays before undertake my WHV in NZ" is meant to be "It was really for holidays before undertaking my WHV in NZ".  Makes sense in the context - applied for non-holiday eVisitor visa, denied, applied for ETA visa, approved, are there going to be issues since they've gotten denied once?  I agree with @wbogacz - she should be fine as she has a valid visa, as long as she didn't answer any questions incorrectly as part of the ETA visa, e.g. have you been denied a visa before?

Comment: I edited your question to improve the English, but I don't know what you wanted to say with "I really for holidays before" so I couldn't fix it and I suppose other English speakers won't understand it either.

Answer (score 1):

eVisitor visas are available only for [passport holders of these countries](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/651.aspx?tab=1&heading=who-could-get-this-visa), all of which are in Europe.  If you are not a citizen of those countries, your eVisitor will definitely be rejected.

But now that you have a valid [ETA](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETA/etas.jsp) -- which implies you hold one of [these passports](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETA/etas.jsp) (click the "Apply online" link for list) -- all is good, and you can enter Australia.

Comment: If I read tge original sentence correctly OP already had an eVisitor visa

Comment: eVisitor is max three months, there's no way you can (legally) spend two years in Australia on one.  But we definitely need some more clarification here...

Comment: Hence the clarification I requested